# Safe to store unencrypted password into HTML5 client side database?

Tags: database, security, html, hash, web-sql

I am assuming the answer is that storing a password in a WEBSQL database on the client side, unencrypted is not safe, but i thought i would ask anyway, the reason I am asking, is I am trying to add a dropbox uploading tool to a web app, but i need the password in plain text in order to access the user's dropbox account, i surely could come up with some foobar way to hash the passwords client side, and unhash them when needed, but if I will be able to unhash them, anyone will be able to do so as well, does anyone have a work around if this is the case?

Comment: If you can unhash them, they're not hashed.

Comment: i understand that, thats basically what i was getting at.

Comment: you probably mean encrypting it. hashing is irreversible

Comment: hahahah you are right, thanks software monkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as 100% secure or safe.  The goal of security is to be safe enough.  You determine what is the risk, and what is the level of pain you are willing to go through and find the sweet spot.

If you have to get a plain text back from a cypher you have no choice but to use encryption not hashing.  Of course you have to have the key somewhere, whether user entered or stored somewhere so the key is vulnerable.

Since this is on a client computer, it may be vulnerable to phishing attacks, social engineering attacks, trojan/keylogger/virus attacks, physical security risks, etc.

storing clear text is a bad idea, but other than that you have to decide what level of pain the users will suffer through.

PKI tokens are a good option if the cost is worth it.  otherwise most languages have many various encryption algorithms that can be used effectively.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not safe to store plaintext passwords, period.

Assuming your users log into your web app with a password, why not use *that* password to encrypt their (salted) dropbox password?  That's still less than satisfactory from a security standpoint, but it's better than nothing.

Using the words "foobar" and "dropbox" in the same paragraph is a clear signal that you're asking for trouble with a home-grown solution.  You're asking your users to trust you with the security of their dropbox data, which means you're accepting an *awful* lot of liability.  You're also asking your users to violate one of the fundamental laws of security: **Never trust your security to a third party.**

The best advice I can offer is to delegate all security-related tasks to an expert, and have that code audited by another expert.